# Angular nested routing is removed by the main router outlet

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-routing

I have a app in which I have a header and a sidebar. It looks like this:

```
#app.component.html
<mat-drawer-container class="sidenav-container">

    <app-side-nav></app-side-nav>

  <mat-drawer-content>
    <app-header></app-header>
    <main>
      <router-outlet></router-outlet>
    </main>
  </mat-drawer-content>
</mat-drawer-container>
```

And routing configuration is:

```
const routes: Routes = [
  { path: 'identity', loadChildren: './identity-registry/identity-registry.module#IdentityRegistryModule' }
];
```

Now upon clicking on identity the `identity module` will load a nested nav menu within it. The identity module has 3 component (IdentityRegistryComponent,MyIdentityComponent, UsersComponent) and it has its own routing configuration.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: '',
    component: IdentityRegistryComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'my-identity',
    component: MyIdentityComponent
  },
  {
    path: 'users',
    component: UsersComponent
  }
];
```

and the nested route looks like this:

```
###IdentityRegistryComponent

<nav mat-tab-nav-bar>
  <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['./my-identity']">My Identity</a>

  <a mat-tab-link [routerLink]="['./users']">Users</a>
</nav>
<router-outlet></router-outlet>
```

But unfortunately, whenever I click on identity, its load the `IdentityRegistryComponent` properly. But click on `my-identity`, disappear the nested routes and load the respective component only. But it should not be like that. The nested loop should be there and upon clicking on `my-identity`, it should load the respective component on `router-outlet`. I do not know how to make it working?

Besides, is there anyway that, if i click on identity from the nav, it will load the `IdentityRegistryComponent` and by default `MyIdentityComponent` will be loaded in a nested routes zone?

for better understanding, i have add the git link: 
[testApp](http://%20github.com/shahin4u000/test)

Answer (score 1):

If you want to use the router outlet for this module, you need to specify the component for this 'child'.

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: 'identity',
  component: AppComponent,
  loadChildren: './identity-registry/identity-registry.module#IdentityRegistryModule'
}];
```

If you want all your routes to use the same component you can also define it like so:

```
const routes: Routes = [{
  path: '',
  component: AppComponent,
  children: [{
      path: 'identity',
      component: NestedNavComponent, // Add a component here for nested router-outlets
      loadChildren: './identity-registry/identity-registry.module#IdentityRegistryModule'
  },{
      path: 'another-route',
      loadChildren: './another-route/another-route.module#AnotherRouteModule'
  }]
}];
```

### Update (**See the nested component reference I added**):

Routes work hierarchical and that includes router-outlets in nested routes. The application is built in layers for child routes. If you consider that, you can define your child routes the same way as you designed your ui logic.

Comment: Hi, unfortunately, it still removes the nested nav which is inside the IdentityRegistryComponent. @Silvermind

Comment: i am so greatful for your effort. but its not working. here is the git link: https://github.com/shahin4u000/test
could you please check once? i will be forever so grateful to you. @Silvermind

Comment: @Kazi You have not implemented my suggestions yet.